# why can't i call variable from other class using object.variable_name?

Tags: java

I have just begun learning Java and I am trying to test stuff by myself. Below is the code where I am getting an error. I am trying to call the local variable in class B in `class Demo` using object of `class B`.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B obj=new B();
        System.out.println("printing that variable "+obj.a);
    }
}
class B{
    public void test()
    {
        int a=10;
    }
}
```

Output:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:  a cannot be resolved or is not a field at
>   Demo.main(Demo.java:7)

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problem" was not your first error message. What was it?

Answer (score 1):

*You can always call, but that needs to be in scope and when the current context have access to.*

```
System.out.println("printing that variable "+obj.a);
```

You cannot do that since the variable `a` is local to the method `test()` and scope is restricted to that method only.

To access the way you want now, make it as a instance member.

```
class B{
int a;  // instance member now
public void test()
{
a=10;
}
}
```

Now note that unless you call the method `test()` the default value is `0` only. Hence you might want to change your code as

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
B obj=new B();
obj.test();
System.out.println("printing that variable "+obj.a);
}
```

and if you don't want to call a method at all want to access `a` directly, you can do

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String args[])
{
B obj=new B();
System.out.println("printing that variable "+obj.a);
}
}
class B{
public int a= 10;
}
```

Imp note :**Always resolve all the compile errors before running your program :)**

Comment: thank you so much :) m at learning stage , will try to clear my doubts and concepts again :)

Comment: @lamiaheart Glad to help. Mark it as an answer if you really helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Because in

```
class B {
    public void test() {
        int a = 10;
    }
}
```

`a` is local variable of `test` method. If what you are trying to do would be possible, what value should be used in scenario like

```
class B {
    public void test1() {
        int a = 10;
    }
    public void test2() {
        int a = 20;
    }
}
```

Should `a` come from `test1` or from `test2`? For compiler this two methods are equally correct so it can't decide for you, which would cause the problem. Also lets not forget that method can have few variables with same name as long as they are in different scope, that is why we can have few `for(int i...)` methods (so from which scope you would want to use `i`).

Generally `.` operator is used to get access to *member of class*, not *variable from method*. So via `object.member` you may access to `object.method()` or `object.field`. If your class would look like

```
class B{
    public int x;
    public void test1() {
        int a = 10;
    }
}
```

you could use `object.b` since `b` is class B *field*.

---

Anyway if you want to get access to value of variable created and used only in method `test`, you could change this method to return this value. In other words you could rewrite it like

```
public int test1() {
    int a = 10;
    //... you can do something with a
    return a;
}
```

Now in main method in `Demo` class you could use `int result = obj.test();`

Comment: Want to add something to your answer.Also Class B is default. So both the classes should be under the same package.

Comment: @Leo True, but lets not involve access modifiers and their relation to place where class is created. Also based on OP example I suspect that `B` is in same `Demo.java` file, which means that it is in same package as `Demo`.